# Handle refresh_token with SYMFONY/LexitJWT & Angular

Tags: angular, symfony, jwt, refresh-token, symfony6

i'm currently doing an Angular + Symfony WebApp.
I did my token interceptor like this

```
@Injectable()
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    // for avoiding entering an infinite loop
    private isRefreshing = false;
    constructor(private _authService: AuthService) { }
    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        if (this._authService.getJwtToken()) {
            request = this.setToken(request, this._authService.getJwtToken()!);
        }

        return next.handle(request).pipe(
            catchError(error => {
                if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse && error.status === 401 && this._authService.getJwtRefreshToken()) {
                    return this.handleAuthorizationError(request, next);
                } else {
                    return throwError(() => error);
                }
            })
        );
    }

    private setToken(request: HttpRequest<any>, token: string): HttpRequest<any> {
        return request.clone({ setHeaders: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` } });
    }

    private handleAuthorizationError(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        if (!this.isRefreshing) {
            this.isRefreshing = true;
            return this._authService.refreshJwtToken().pipe(
                switchMap((token: JwtToken) => {
                    this.isRefreshing = false;
                    this._authService.setJwtToken(token);
                    return next.handle(this.setToken(request, token.token));
                }
                )
            );
        } else {
            this.isRefreshing = false;
            return next.handle(request);
        }
    }
}
```

And currently my token_ttl in Symfony is set at 84600 for 1D.

I'm trying to refresh my token even if my main token is expired.
But, when my token is expiring, my refresh token is expiring too.

How can I solve my problem to keep a constant auth foreach http request even if the user didnt connect like 2 weeks ago ?

Should I extend my refresh_token expiration ? How to do it ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem :

Symfony is checking the JWT Token expiration before the URL Action itself even with PUBLIC_ACCESS set in security.yaml.

So I had to remove the Authorization header if JWT Token is expired like this :

```
 private setToken(request: HttpRequest<any>, token: string): HttpRequest<any> {
        if ( this._authService.isTokenExpired() ) {
          return request;
        }
        return request.clone({ setHeaders: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` } });
    }
```

Hope this will be usefull for someone :)